# PHP scripts changing to random characters when uploading FTP

Tags: php, ftp, ascii, filezilla

A bit of a strange problem here.

I am using FileZilla and Notepad++ on my work machine.

Basically whenever I upload a PHP script all the code turns into random characters

For example this code:

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

turns into

```
<?php ਍攀挀栀漀 ✀栀攀氀氀漀✀㬀ഀ ?>
```

My FTP transfer mode is set to ASCII. Am I doing anything wrong,  is it a bad FTP setting?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Are you able to switch from ascii to utf-8 ?

Comment: Does notepad++ let you juggle your file encoding? (as mnmnc says). If not try with an IDE.

Comment: I don't think it is a notepad++ setting as regular notepad does the exact same.  the strange part is it keeps the <?php tags. Also it isn't a server configuration as it works in the house fine.  I will try notepad++ settings

Comment: Now it uploads as normal now, but the script doesn't execute,  this is a strange one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ftp client botches the characterset of your input. Change the upload mode to binary and you're done.

Comment: Does my encoding matter in y editor,  I am using UTF-8 t the moment

Comment: Strange, I tried it on Binary last night and all day yesterday, now its working fine!? I got rid of my current script (which I wrote) and switched to codigniter and its working great! I still think it was a binary/acsii issue so your getting the answer,  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

good luck for your new office! xD

ftp trasfer with ASCII mode is (was) useful only if you are using plain text files and only if you have code, a script, that needs text files correctly encoded.

**the ASCII mode actually means "handle this file as a text file"**

text files that you **may** need to encode correctly are the "really text ones":
**txt, ini, conf** (php outputs html/xml, then line endings are not relevant)

the replacements made by FTP ASCII mode, to the line ending bytes(s), may corrupt the entire file, with some encodings... actually this should not happen with UTF-8, then, apparently, you are using some other encoding...

in my opinion, in 2012, it is better to keep the file as it is uploaded: the client, the scripts and the applications should be able to parse correctly any text file of any system.

then: **upload as binary, and be sure your scripts can handle any line ending bytes sequences**

for instance if you need to split by line endings, use

```
// works everywhere with any file with any line ending
preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $text);
```

instead of

```
// works everywhere but only with files that contain
// line endings equivalent to the actual PHP_EOL content
explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

hoping to have been clear...
feel free to correct my english!